# What HTTP status response code return if the request is missing or wrong value(multiple choice) path parameter?

Tags: rest, api, http

A REST API with path parameter: /search/{option} , the {option} parameter has a list of possible values "A","B","C". GET method is only used.

What is the appropriated status code to give when {option} parameter is passed with worng value( for example "D")? and if the parameter is missing?

If the path parameter is missing the final endpoint: /search/ This service doesn't exist.

Comment: Ask yourself whether there's a representation available for the request URI. No? Then the answer should be 404.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the appropriated status code to give when {option} parameter is passed with worng value( for example "D")? and if the parameter is missing?

[404](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)

> The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource

The [target resource](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.1) is the resource identified by the [request line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1) as the request-target.  So in a request that begins...

```
GET /search/D HTTP/1.1
```

The target resource is that resource corresponding to the identifier `/search/D`.

Since `/search/D` is not a resource in your application, it doesn't have a current representation, and therefore `404` is the correct response -- it's the way that we announce to the client (and intermediate components) that there was a spelling error in the request-target.

The fact that your implementation routes requests to `/search/D` to the same function that handles `/search/A`, `/search/B`, and `/search/C` is an accident of your implementation, and need not be considered when designing your response.

The same argument holds for

```
GET /search/ HTTP/1.1
GET /search HTTP/1.1
```

You might, as part of the body of the response, send a message that describes some of the obvious alternative spellings :

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Did you mean?

/search/A
/search/B
/search/C
```

`404` responses are cacheable by default - generic clients can store the returned representation for later use, without needing to interpret the payload.

Comment: When the parameter value is wrong(different that list expected ), is it possible to response as HTTP 300 Multiple Choices???